# Express timediff as tenth of an hour

Tags: mysql

Would like to add a record with the difference between two date/times
expressed as tenths of an hour

e.g Start   2014-06-19 15:30:00
    End     2014-06-19 18:00:00
    Result  2.5

so far have

```
   SELECT 
   LEFT(
       (REPLACE(
           TIMEDIFF('2014-06-19 18:00:00','2014-06-19 15:30:00')
       ,':','.')
    ),5
    )/6
```

Which gives result 0.383 = not correct, any ideas welcome TQ

Comment: Got correct result with

SELECT ROUND(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-19 18:00:00') -  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-19 15:30:00')) / 3600),1)

TQ Marcell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate with seconds:

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_a) -  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_b)) / 360
```

Comment: For tenths of an hour it would be `/ 360`